# Enter entire Text block into File in powershell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to put a large block of text into a Textfile but i cant find a way to do so with the amount of special characters/stuff it contains.
I already tried the @" -> "@ method which did not work either.
I also want it to not write the values behind variables but just everything like it is in the Textblock.
Is there a more elegant way to do this than figuring something out for each line?

Basically im trying to generate a working powershell file with it.
There might be a better way to do this which i am not aware of.

This is the powershell script:

```
$t = @"
$InstallPath = (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Where-Object {$_.GetValue("DisplayName") -like "ABBYY FlexiCapture 12 Stations"} | Select-Object -First 1).GetValue("InstallLocation")+'FlexiBRSvc.exe'

$sqlText = "SELECT distinct C.Id as ProjektId,
    B.Name as DokDef,
    D.Name as Dataset
  FROM [Template] as A
  inner join (SELECT TemplateId, MAX(Version) as Version FROM [TemplateVersion] group by TemplateId) as V on A.Id = V.TemplateId 
  inner join [TemplateVersion] as B on V.TemplateId = B.TemplateId and V.Version = B.Version
  inner join [Project] as C on A.ProjectId = C.Id 
  inner join [ProjectDBCache] as D on A.Id = D.TemplateId 
  where A.IsDisabled = 0 and A.IsDeleted = 0 and C.EnableHotFolder <> 0";

$connection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$database");
$cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlText, $connection);

$connection.Open();
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($reader.Read())
{
    $row = New-Object string[] 3;
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
    {
        $row[$i] = $reader.GetValue($i);
    }
    $test = '"'+$InstallPath+'"'+' please update dataset '+'"http://'+$server+'/'+$row[0]+'" "'+$row[1]+'" "'+$row[2]+'"';
    cmd.exe /c $test >> C:\ABBYYFCD\Scripts\powerlog.txt         
}
$connection.Close();
"@
Set-Content -Path C:\ABBYYFCD\TEST\test.ps1 -Value $t
```

And this is the Result:

```
C:\Program Files\ABBYY FlexiCapture 12 Stations\FlexiBRSvc.exe = (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Where-Object {.GetValue("DisplayName") -like "ABBYY FlexiCapture 12 Stations"} | Select-Object -First 1).GetValue("InstallLocation")+'FlexiBRSvc.exe'

SELECT distinct C.Id as ProjektId,
    B.Name as DokDef,
    D.Name as Dataset
  FROM [Template] as A
  inner join (SELECT TemplateId, MAX(Version) as Version FROM [TemplateVersion] group by TemplateId) as V on A.Id = V.TemplateId 
  inner join [TemplateVersion] as B on V.TemplateId = B.TemplateId and V.Version = B.Version
  inner join [Project] as C on A.ProjectId = C.Id 
  inner join [ProjectDBCache] as D on A.Id = D.TemplateId 
  where A.IsDisabled = 0 and A.IsDeleted = 0 and C.EnableHotFolder <> 0 = "SELECT distinct C.Id as ProjektId,
    B.Name as DokDef,
    D.Name as Dataset
  FROM [Template] as A
  inner join (SELECT TemplateId, MAX(Version) as Version FROM [TemplateVersion] group by TemplateId) as V on A.Id = V.TemplateId 
  inner join [TemplateVersion] as B on V.TemplateId = B.TemplateId and V.Version = B.Version
  inner join [Project] as C on A.ProjectId = C.Id 
  inner join [ProjectDBCache] as D on A.Id = D.TemplateId 
  where A.IsDisabled = 0 and A.IsDeleted = 0 and C.EnableHotFolder <> 0";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=WIN-7VGFFP7ECCE;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ABBYYFCD");
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SELECT distinct C.Id as ProjektId,
    B.Name as DokDef,
    D.Name as Dataset
  FROM [Template] as A
  inner join (SELECT TemplateId, MAX(Version) as Version FROM [TemplateVersion] group by TemplateId) as V on A.Id = V.TemplateId 
  inner join [TemplateVersion] as B on V.TemplateId = B.TemplateId and V.Version = B.Version
  inner join [Project] as C on A.ProjectId = C.Id 
  inner join [ProjectDBCache] as D on A.Id = D.TemplateId 
  where A.IsDisabled = 0 and A.IsDeleted = 0 and C.EnableHotFolder <> 0, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection);

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

while (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read())
{
    1 Invoice Vendors = New-Object string[] 3;
    for (3 = 0; 3 -lt System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.FieldCount; 3++)
    {
        1 Invoice Vendors[3] = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(3);
    }
    "C:\Program Files\ABBYY FlexiCapture 12 Stations\FlexiBRSvc.exe" please update dataset "http://WIN-7VGFFP7ECCE/1" "Invoice" "Vendors" = '"'+C:\Program Files\ABBYY FlexiCapture 12 Stations\FlexiBRSvc.exe+'"'+' please update dataset '+'"http://'+WIN-7VGFFP7ECCE+'/'+1 Invoice Vendors[0]+'" "'+1 Invoice Vendors[1]+'" "'+1 Invoice Vendors[2]+'"';
    cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\ABBYY FlexiCapture 12 Stations\FlexiBRSvc.exe" please update dataset "http://WIN-7VGFFP7ECCE/1" "Invoice" "Vendors" >> C:\ABBYYFCD\Scripts\powerlog.txt         
}
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Best way is to read results into a dataset and then save the table to a text file.  See example of c# code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?force_isolation=true&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: Probably to clearest and easiest way to do this, is using a simple scriptblock: `$t = { <your PowerShell> }`, it will automatically cast to a (multiline) string if you save it to a file. As an aside, I recommend you to [Avoid Using Semicolons (;) as Line Terminators](https://poshcode.gitbook.io/powershell-practice-and-style/style-guide/code-layout-and-formatting#avoid-using-semicolons-as-line-terminators) (in the PowerShell part).

Comment: the problem with your code is the use of `@"...."@` instead of  `@'...'@`

Comment: Thank you, both of your Solutions worked and were even more embarrasingly easy than i expected

Comment: no need to be embarrassed, just remember, variables expand when in double quotes. Single quotes are interpreted as string literals.

Answer (score 1):

As commented the solution would be to use either a simple scriptblock
`$t = { <your PowerShell> }` or using `@' '@` instead of `@" "@`